# Prevent Nginx to serve php files unless php-fpm is also working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Recently I discovered my server is outputting php code out. The cause is that nginx is working but the php-fpm is not. As you can imagine this can be a serious security threat.

So is there a way to prevent nginx to serve php files unless it is receiving response from the php engine? I think it is some simple tweak in nginx.conf but I haven't sort that out yet.Hope someone can help!

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name example.com;


location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php  index.html index.htm;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. `fastcgi_pass` shouldn't fallback to serving the PHP as a static file like that.

Comment: I think the problem is not fastcgi serving the static file, rather nginx fetches the static file itself.

Comment: What is causing PHP-FPM to fail?  What is in the logs?  It should really die on you out of the blue

Comment: Hi in this case I perhaps did some upgrading job to cause pph-fpm to stop. But I am concerned if there is such a way to prevent bad security flaw as mentioned.

Comment: Did you not UAT your system after an upgrade?

Answer (score -3):

Your could write a cron job to verify php-fpm service is running and if it is not, swap out nginx .conf files and restart nginx.

Comment: Which'd leave you with source code exposed for up to a minute until cron runs, and a broken server after the "fix".

Comment: True, you could always add a call in your HTML to verify the service is up and conditionality pass PHP or HTML on the fly.  -- The real question is why does PHP-FPM fail?  I wouldnt even have the site up if you cannot rely on it to work properly.

Comment: "A call in your HTML"? What?!

Comment: Well you can have javascript or call and check for a process running on your server.  Or have a call to Java or along the lines of that.  Not straight HTML, but in your webpage, have a system call to verify the service it up and running.

Comment: You're really not making any sense. If JavaScript's able to check PHP-FPM's status, you've got a badly insecure config going. HTML can't "have a call to Java"... and given that the HTML is usually generated **by PHP**, it wouldn't work regardless.

Comment: You can certainly get it to verify if a PID file exists.  There are 100 ways to verify a service is running from a webpage.  It's not a good way to do this, but its obvious this guy doesn't have his server configured correctly anyways, so he has much bigger issues.  I wouldnt run a production server in this state, he is asking for trouble as it is.

Comment: How are you going to get HTML to verify a PID file's existence, and how is that HTML going to exist if the PHP subsystem generating said HTML is down?

Comment: Put an HTML index/landing page that does the check, if it passes route to your PHP page.  Otherwise display a funny 404 page.  It's not ideal but it will work, and that is what is he asking for until he fixes his server.

Comment: You're still glossing over the fact that HTML/JS shouldn't ever be able to access a PID file, port 9000, etc. on the server.

Comment: Shouldn't be and can't are two different things.  This can certainly be accomplished with a little creativity and would address his issue.

Comment: Opening big security holes is sure as hell "creativity"...

Comment: More of a security hole than he already has?  And it's not that bad of an security issue, just think through what has to be done to make this work.  It's obviously a temporary work around until he fixes the real issue.  What he should do is roll back his server from a backup to his last know working state, than troubleshoot this on his dev box.  It's what backups and DR are for.